# Perl function for escaping characters for Windows commands

Tags: windows, perl, cmd

I have a string in Perl which contains various special characters and I need to pass this string to a Windows command using backticks, but I don't want the special characters to mess up the command. I have found out that with Windows commands, different special characters need to be escaped in different ways. Is there a Perl function which has been specially created to escape a string in such a way as to prepare it for a Windows command?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there's [`Win32::ShellQuote`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Win32::ShellQuote), which should do what you want.